# Show array of URI as GIF Android using AnimationDrawble

Tags: java, android, gif, animationdrawable

So I basically have a List of URIs, each has a .jpeg file, and I want to show this list like a GIF file (not necessesary to make a gif, only to display).

So after a research I found the AnimationDrawble object, converted each URI into Drawable and added it as a frame to AnimationDrawable.

This is my code:

```
AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
            Drawable[] dr = new Drawable[position+1];
            ProgressItem pi;

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++) {
                    pi = progress.get(i);

                    try {
                        dr[i] = drawableFromUrl(pi.getImage());
                    } catch (IOException ios) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, ios.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(activity, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(activity,ProgressImage.class);
            DataWraper.setItems(dr);
```

drawableFromUrl:

```
 public Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    MyDownloadTask mdt = new MyDownloadTask();
    try{
       mdt.execute(connection);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(activity, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    InputStream input = mdt.getInputStream();

    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return new BitmapDrawable(x);
}
```

The implementation part:

```
 Glide.with(this)
                    .load(ad)
                    .into(progressImage);
```

When I'm trying to Glide the AnimationDrawble into the ImageView I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type class android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.
```

This made me hesistate the way I'm trying to pull this off. Should this be this complicated?

If this is the right way, what am I doing wrong? maybe there's another way of doing so? I'd love to get some details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use Glide here?  You've already loaded the Drawables.  Just set the image view's drawable directly.  The place to use Glide would be to download and cache the individual images.

Comment: @GabeSechan already tried. The general idea is when I perform a click on something it will put a single image in it (from a URI too), and in a long click it will show the procces of all the images through until the one pressed. When I tried setting the single picture and change it directly through the ImageView it didn't work, but with the Glide it did, so I figured it will stay the same with the LongClick, yet it won't work either way rn.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable
Not sure if you're open to any 3rd party libraries, but i used this one for gifs before and it worked quite well for me

Comment: I'll try this and keep you posted